# Twitter Bootstrap: Hide sub-menus in small screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If we have submenus then they are visible by default and we have to scroll and scroll. Plz have a look what I want but it is for Bootstrap's previous versions. I am figuring out for 2.1.1 and I believe it should be default feature in Bootstrap (they've changed many things in newer versions)

Plz have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nczJF/

I am looking for such menu behavior where main menu and sub menus appear only by clicking on relevant sub-menu. I've searched a lot but all of them are for Bootstraps's previous versions. 
So anybody with expert advice?

Comment: The JSFiddle works that way for me. I have to manually open up the menu, and then manually open up each submenu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nczJF/39/

This uses the most recent version of bootstrap. The only difference is CSS, the JS is the same.

In bootstrap-responsive.css, remove `display: block` (don't switch to display none) from:

```
.nav-collapse .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  float: none;
  display: block; /* remove this line! */
  max-width: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0;
          border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     -moz-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}
```

In the same file, towards the bottom, change `height: 0` to `height: auto`:

```
.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse.collapse {
  height: auto; /* instead of 0 */
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Then, to fix the default expanded view, change your html. Add the class `collapsed` to the collapse button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

Also change

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
```

to

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
```

This could be more graceful with editing JS but this works without changing another file.

I'm pushing for integration for this feature here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5606

Comment: Thanks a lot Archonic! You've solved a big problem in bootstrap! And yes it must be included by default. 
And there are some more things regarding this issue and I am sure you can solve them too. 
1)How can we set the height of this menu? 
i.e. If we have a lot of sub menus, we should fix the total height of the menu so user may not scroll all the down but he should scroll from the scroll bar on his right side to see further menus.
2)If we have further menus in submenus, they collapse on mouse hover in mobile view. So how can we change it on click rather then just hover?
Regards

Comment: 1) Fixing the height of the menu would limit the options you could add to it. To not limit yourself, I'd recommend editing the .less files for the navbar component. I'm not exactly sure what you mean- try starting a new jsfiddle and explain what behavior you want. 2) You can see mobile resolutions on a desktop but mobile users don't have a mouse so there's no hover action. The exception is if they're using a certain type of stylus. Still, it shouldn't happen and I'll look into it - might just be an html problem. Again, a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: Please have a look on following website. When we re-size the browser window to mobile view, the menu appears as a dropdown list with fixed height. There are a lot of menus and submenus but they appear in fixed height which is not possessing the whole viewable area of screen but just a fixed height and we have to scroll down just the menu area to view more menus. Although this demo website is not built into bootstrap but if we could implement such behavior in our bootstrap.... 
http://themes.goodlayers.com/modernize/

Comment: Ah! That's actually a totally different HTML element called "select". If you recreate your menu within a select tag and give it the class "visible-phone" and give your existing menu a class "hidden-phone", it will appear that your menu shrunk down to a fixed height dropdown menu. Note that selecting items within a "select" tag menu will have a rolodex type UI on iPhones.

Comment: Hi mrto2, want to hit the checkmark to mark this as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I would if I could but since you're the author of the questions, only you are allowed. It's right under the upvote/downvote number thingy.